# PHP PNG Image Upload losing transparency

Tags: php, gd

I am trying to upload image using the php GD functions and I have found many solutions to properly upload the image without loosing transparency. I have tried to use most of them but due to some reason I failed every time. My code is

```
switch($ext) {
    case 'PNG':
    case 'png':
        $oImage = imagecreatefrompng($sFileName);
    break;

    case 'GIF':
    case 'gif':
        $oImage = imagecreatefromgif($sFileName);
    break;

    default:
        $oImage = imagecreatefromjpeg($sFileName);
    break;
}

$kW = $aSize[0] / $params['size']['width'];
$kH = $aSize[1] / $params['size']['height'];
if($kW > $kH) {
    $w1 = round($params['size']['width'] * $kH);
    $h1 = $aSize[1];
}
else {
    $w1 = $aSize[0];
    $h1 = round($params['size']['height'] * $kW);
}

$oBuffer = ImageCreateTrueColor($params['size']['width'], $params['size']['height']); 
ImageCopyResampled($oBuffer, $oImage, 0, 0, 0, 0, $params['size']['width'], $params['size']['height'], $w1, $h1); 

if(file_exists($sFileName)) {
    unlink($sFileName);
}

imagejpeg($oBuffer, $sFileName);
// Also tried 
imagepng($oBuffer, $sFileName);
return $sFilename;
```

Can anyone help me point out my mistake please..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution I think will do the trick for you.

```
$oBuffer = ImageCreateTrueColor($params['size']['width'], $params['size']['height']);
        imagealphablending($oBuffer, false);
        imagesavealpha($oBuffer, true);  
        imagealphablending($oImage, true);
        imagecopyresampled($oBuffer, $oImage, 0, 0, 0, 0, $params['size']['width'],     $params['size']['height'], $w1, $h1); 
        if(file_exists($sFileName)) {
            unlink($sFileName);
        }
        imagepng($oBuffer, $sFileName);
        chmod($sFileName, 0777);
        return $sFileName;
```

Notice that I have used imagealphablending two times and also the point which DMSJax pointed out.
Hope that helps. Cheers.

Comment: Yes I see how you have used alpha blending once with false and then again true. I guess this is what I was missing. This is working now thanks a lot. You saved my day.

Answer (score 3):

Regardless of your input filetype and transparency, your are outputting a jpg/jpeg " imagejpeg($oBuffer, $sFileName); " which is a format that doesn't support transparency. Output to proper filetype that supports transparency.

Comment: Fair enough, I answered it based on the code provided and an obvious problem.

Comment: @Yunus ok, you still need to use png, if you convert to jpg, you WILL lose that transparency no matter what

Comment: Yes Lukas1 I tried first with imagepng and it did not work.. So I just got fed up and tried with imagejpeg as well but that didnt work too.. :( Answer by Majeed worked out for me...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `imagecopyresized()` instead of `ImageCopyResampled()` ?

Comment: Let me try that.. I haven't tried that yet.. Will post you back in a moment.